# Can't get video thumbnail previews working for a samba share (Dolphin/Nautilus/Nemo)

Tags: 16.04, kubuntu, nautilus, nemo, previews

I'm running `Kubuntu 16.04` and the stock file browser (`Dolphin`) fails to render any video thumbnail previews at all <strike>locally</strike> or on a samba share. *Edit: Sliding the icon size bar to `96+ pixels` causes the thumbnails to render locally - still no remote share rendering though.*

I've installed `Nautilus` and video thumbnail previews work locally but not remotely. Supposedly there is a setting to enable thumbnails from all sources (defaulted to only work on local for some reason). Except on `Kubuntu`, there is *no* way to access the preferences menu. I get that if I was running `GNOME` I'd be able to access it via the top bar menu but it's effectively broken in `Kubuntu` and you get nothing. Alt button does nothing either.

I then installed `Nemo` and thought I finally almost had it when it worked locally and there was an accessible preferences menu (holy crap I've taken that for granted) and even after specifying to generate thumbnails always (local/remote) and even after specifying to do it for files up to 100mb when the biggest videos are like 4mb, it *still* does **not** work! Even rebooted.

I've installed every `'*thumb*'` package from `synaptic` I could find that seemed relevant.

I'm at my whits end on this one. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get them working in Dolphin:

```
sudo apt install ffmpegthumbs
```

due to a bug in KDE5 you might have to

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/plugins/* /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/
```

Then open Dolphin

Control --> Configure Dolphin --> General --> Previews

Enable previews for Video Files and enter into the

```
Skip previews for remote Files above:
```

a sufficiently high value

Checked on Ubuntu 16.04 with KDE 5.6

Comment: I did already do that. Interestingly though I did discover one new thing. I can get the `local thumbnails` to work in `Dolphin` by changing the pixel resolution on the lower right to `96+`. Anything below `96` pixels does not render thumbnails. At least theres some consistency now.

Comment: @Enigma Have you tried creating the symbolic links as in my improved answer. It helped me get pdf previews working....

Comment: Ah.. very nice - works perfectly for me for video thumbnails and all.

Comment: is there a way to achieve this without root permissions? I have tried to have `~/.local/lib` in place of `/usr/lib` when relevant, but with no luck.